# Starting a theorem or a proof with an equation and vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, equations, theorems, nesting

Is it bad practice to begin the statement of a `theorem` or of a `proof` with an `equation`? If it is acceptable, what is your opinion on the resulting spacing in the three cases, in the code below?

In the case of the statement of the first two `facts` my desired result would be to have the equation(s) starting on the same line as Fact 0.1 etc.

For the proof, I am not sure whether it looks fine this way, or whether it would be better typesetting to have the equations starting on the same line as Proof.

And in both cases I am wondering what would be the best way to achieve these changes.

Thanks for reading.

```
\documentclass[draft,11pt]{article}
\sloppy

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}



\begin{document}

\newcommand{\diam}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1 \rangle}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newcommand{\N}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{N}}}

  \begin{fact}\label{fact:stillnotguarded}
     \begin{equation*}
        \text{ST}_x([!\N]\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p) \textup{ is not guarded.}
    \end{equation*}
\end{fact}

\medskip

\begin{fact}\label{fact:stillnotguarded}
     \begin{align*}
        \text{ST}_x([!\N]\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p) \textup{ is not guarded.}\\
        \text{ST}_x([!\N]\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p) \textup{ is loosely guarded.}
    \end{align*}
\end{fact}


\medskip

\begin{fact}\label{fact:notguarded}
    $\text{ST}_x([!\N]\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p)$ is not guarded.
\end{fact}
\begin{proof}  
    \begin{align*}
      & ST_x([!\N]\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p)\\
      & = ST_x(\diam{a}[!\N]\diam{b}p^x)\\
      & = \exists y (\N(x,y) \wedge R_a(x,y) \wedge
      ST_y([!\N]\diam{b}p^x))\\
      & = \exists y (\N(x,y) \wedge R_a(x,y) \wedge ST_y(\diam{b}p^{xy}))\\
      & = \exists y (\N(x,y) \wedge R_a(x,y) \wedge (\exists z(\N(y,z) \wedge R_b(y,z)        \wedge ST_y(p^{xy}))))\\
      & = \exists y (\N(x,y) \wedge R_a(x,y) \wedge (\exists z(\N(y,z) \wedge R_b(y,z) \wedge R_p(y)))) \qedhere
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion is better to start writing a little bit even few words to prepare what is coming next. For example *Considering...*

Comment: In the first two I'd rather write them undisplayed. But I have nothing against them being displayed. Same with the proof. It looks better if at least a little bit of text starts it, but if there is no need for it, then that is fine., But I do not think it would look good to have the formulas displayed and have the first line on the same line as the theorem/proof header, that is not nice.

Comment: It is bad practice, in my opinion. Unless you're doing formal logic, theorems and proofs should start with text.