# Avoid linebreak when starting “proof” environment with “align” environment

Tags: align, amsthm

Under `amsthm`, if the first content in a `proof` environment consists of a displayed equation, or an `align` or similar environment, the linebreak after the “*Proof.*” heading is (to my taste) rather undesirable.

In the case of a single equation, I know how to forestall this linebreak (albeit rather kludgily).  **How can I avoid this linebreak in the case of an `align` or similar environment?**

(This is a partial duplicate of [Starting a theorem or a proof with an equation and vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155221/starting-a-theorem-or-a-proof-with-an-equation-and-vertical-spacing), which also asks “Is it bad style to start a proof this way?”; the only answers there are comments are comment saying “Yes, it is bad style”, and not addressing the technical aspect.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $(x+1)(x-1) + 1 = x^2$.
\end{theorem}

Single equation, with initial linebreak:
%
\begin{proof}
 \[  (x+1)(x-1) + 1 = (x^2 - x + x + 1) + 1 = x^2  \qedhere \]
\end{proof}

Single equation, without initial linebreak:
%
\begin{proof}
 \hfill $  (x+1)(x-1) + 1 = (x^2 - x + x + 1) + 1 = x^2  $ \hfill
\end{proof}

Multiple equation, with initial linebreak:
%
\begin{proof}
 \begin{align*}
   (x+1)(x-1) + 1 &= x(x-1) + 1(x-1) + 1 \\
    &= (x^2 - x) + (x - 1) + 1)  \\
    &= x^2 + (- x + x) + (-1 + 1)  \\
    &= x^2 && \qedhere
 \end{align*}
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is bad style. `;-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use an `{aligned}` environment with a `[t]` positioning specifier.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it holds that $(x+1)(x-1)+1=x^2$.
\end{theorem}

\noindent
Single-line equation, \emph{without} initial linebreak:
\begin{proof}\quad
$\displaystyle (x+1)(x-1) + 1 = (x^2 - x + x + 1) + 1 = x^2$ 
\end{proof}

\medskip\noindent
Multi-line equation, \emph{without} initial linebreak:
\begin{proof}\quad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
   (x+1)(x-1) + 1 &= x(x-1) + 1(x-1) + 1 \\
    &= (x^2 - x) + (x - 1) + 1)  \\
    &= x^2 + (- x + x) + (-1 + 1)  \\
    &= x^2 && \qedhere
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: if the equations have to be centered horizontally and the QED symbol has to be placed on the far right, flush with the right-hand edge of the textblock, I suggest you use the following, modified code.

```
\noindent
Single-line equation, \emph{without} initial linebreak:
\begin{proof}
\hfill$\displaystyle (x+1)(x-1) + 1 = (x^2 - x + x + 1) + 1 = x^2$\hfill
\end{proof}

\medskip\noindent
Multi-line equation, \emph{without} initial linebreak:
\begin{proof}
\hfill$\begin{aligned}[t]
   (x+1)(x-1) + 1 
       &= x(x-1) + 1(x-1) + 1 \\
       &= (x^2 - x) + (x - 1) + 1)  \\
       &= x^2 + (- x + x) + (-1 + 1)  \\
       &= x^2 & \qquad\qquad\qedhere
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Comment: Your final `\hfill` doesn't do a thing, because the following implied `\par` undoes it. So you must resort to adjusting the spacing by hand, as you did here with `\qquad\qquad`. I actually think my solution is cleaner (but the voters disagree, so I *could* be mistaken about that).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - Thanks for this. I've edited the second code block to omit the final `\hfill` directive.

Answer (score 6):

You could try adding this immediately after `\begin{proof}`:

```
\leavevmode\vadjust{\kern\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip\relax}
```

If your alignment is wide, the first line might overlap the word *Proof.* To avoid this, add `\phantom{\text{\itshape Proof.}}\quad` to the beginning of the first line of your alignment.

Answer (score 4):

More or less in the vein of @Harald-Hanche-Olsen's answer,  I define a `\raisegroup` command to be used just after `\begin{proof}` and a `\centregroup` to be used on entering the equation environment if you want to take  into account the length of the proof label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlength{\movedby}
\settowidth{\movedby}{\textit{Proof.}}
\newcommand\centregroup{\hspace*{0.5\movedby}}
\newcommand{\raisegroup}{\leavevmode\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $(x+1)(x-1) + 1 = x^2$.
\end{theorem}

Single equation:
%
\begin{proof}\raisegroup
 \[ \centregroup(x+1)(x-1) + 1 = (x^2 - x + x + 1) + 1 = x^2 \qedhere \]
\end{proof}

Multiple equation:
%
\begin{proof}\raisegroup
 \begin{align*}
 (x+1)(x-1) + 1 &= x(x-1) + 1(x-1) + 1 \\
    &= (x^2 - x) + (x - 1) + 1) \\
    &= x^2 + (- x + x) + (-1 + 1) \\
    &= x^2 && \qedhere
 \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a new environment called `mathonlyproof` (or whatever), is better. But I'd discourage such formula only proofs.

Comment: I agree with you. However there may be some rare special cases for which it might be useful.

Comment: “The above answer” is rather ambiguous, don't you think? The order seems to change according to votes, the moon phase, and possibly other factors. I like it, though. Perhaps because I imagine it is my answer you are referring to. ;-)

Comment: It  is indeed.  I'll fix my answer, as you're no more ‘above’ ;o)

Comment: This answer and @HaraldHanche-Olsen’s seem very clean, but they have one issue which unfortunately doesn’t show up in the example from my MEW.  When the first line of the equations contains anything taller than normal text (e.g. a superscript `$x^2$`), then the vertical alignment will not be quite right — that is, the baseline of the first equation won’t match the baseline of “Proof” (which seems to me the desirable alignment; it matches what e.g. inline math following the “Proof” gives).  The best fix I’ve found is to pass the tall content as an argument to `\raisegroup`… [cont’d]

Comment: …and adjust the calculated vertical height of the raise, using the vertical height of that argument.  Can you see a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: That's a good point. I think you could achieve the same effect by wrapping a `\smash{…}` around the first line of the alignment, except that has a further bad side effect of erasing the *depth* of that line. I suppose you could remedy that by creating a variant of `\smash` that zeroes only the height and not the depth.

Comment: However, this approach will fail if the first line of the alignment is *really* tall, like a matrix or something. But in that case, perhaps it will be better to abandon the notion of lining the equation up with the word *Proof*. I think it might look silly, in fact. Then there are in-between cases, where the first line contains sums or integrals. For that, perhaps just add some vertical space before the proof environment.

Comment: Re smashing the top only: `amsmath` has `\smash[t]{…}` that does that.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen or OP, can you give explicit latex code using the \smash solution? I have a case with exponents that exhibits this problem.